# NameError: unitialized constant in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So, I'm running Rspec, and trying to figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: 3.times {@post.votes.create(value: 1) }
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Vote::PostId
```

Here is my spec/models/post_spec.rb file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Post do
describe "vote methods" do

before do
  @post = Post.create(title: 'post title', body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.')
  3.times {@post.votes.create(value: 1) }
  2.times {@post.votes.create(value: -1) }
end

describe '#up_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with value = 1" do
    expect( @post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
  end
end

describe '#down_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with value = -1" do
    expect( @post.down_votes ).to eq(2)
  end
end

describe '#points' do
  it "returns the sum of all down and up votes" do
    expect( @post.points ).to eq(1) # 3 - 2
  end
end
end
end
```

I don't understand why it's giving that line as the error, since its creating data for the Rspec to execute. And when trying to find the "Vote::PostId" in any of my files, it can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @post.votes.build(value: 1)

Create is used on class. So it can be either Post.create or Vote.create.

In your case, it will try to search for Vote::PostId, such a class does not exist.

Comment: `@post.votes` returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` upon which `create` can be called, so `@post.votes.create(value: 1)` is legit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find `PostId` in your `Vote` class? Maybe you were trying to specify a foreign key and typed `PostId` rather than `"PostId"`?